# How to change Styles using NgClass Conditional?

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have a form with some fields. I splitted the fields in three forms groups.

How i could get, in HTML, the NgClass conditional?

I've tried something like this:

Ts model file:

```
export class Rule {
id: number;
name: string;
```

TS file:

```
export class RegrasModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

// Propriedades Input do componente
  @Input() title: string;
 @Input() rule: Rule;

ngOnInit() {
this.ruleForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  dataInicio: ['', Validators.required],
  dataFim: ['', Validators.required],
  cell: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="step" [(ngModel)]="rule.name" type="text" id="name"
                                                formControlName="name" nbInput fullWidth placeholder="Descripción"
                                                [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': rule.name.valid }" />
```

I received this message:
Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Could someone help me, pease?

Comment: `cannot read property of undefined` always means the same thing.  You are attempting to read a value from a property (`valid` in this case) from a variables that has no valid (*undefined*).  You should populate the name property with a value.

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to know if have a value on the field 'name'.

Answer (score 1):

the property `name` of the object `rule` does not exists. Perhaps you were looking to access the object `ruleForm`, as defined in your `ngOnInit` function ?

```
[ngClass]="{ 'has-error': ruleForm.name.valid }"
```

Comment: I'm going to test this.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegrasModalComponent.html:10)

Comment: There is no property `value` in your `Rule` object. @Bisneto

Comment: Thank you Nicolas! Very very very good the answer. But actually doesn't help. but maaaany thanks!